# Bubble sorting in double-linked list leading to trying to read from NULL

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to code *bubble sort* to order a linked list by comparison. The problem is that, at some point, the bubble sort function sends a NULL pointer to the comparison function, which leads to a runtime error. Specifically, the last item of the list points to NULL.

The idea is to do the first iteration seperately. This way I can get the number of times the list is compared at the first time; then, I can use this number to continue sorting in a different loop.

Here is the code. Thanks for the help.

```
void SortItemList(Item* ptrFirstItem, 
                  int(*compare)(const Item*,const Item*))
{
  Item* currentItem=ptrFirstItem;
  Item* nextItem;
  int itemSize=0;
  int i,j;

  //in case no items or just one
  if (currentItem==NULL || currentItem->nextItem==NULL)
    return;
  else
    {
      //first iteration also checking how many items to compare
      nextItem=currentItem->nextItem;
      while(nextItem!=NULL)
        {
          itemSize++;

          if(compare(currentItem, nextItem)>0)
            swapItems(currentItem, nextItem);

          currentItem=nextItem;
          nextItem=nextItem->nextItem;
        }
      itemSize--;

      for(i=0;i<itemSize;i++)
        {
          currentItem=ptrFirstItem;
          nextItem=currentItem->nextItem;

          for(j=0;j<itemSize-i;j++)
            {
              if(compare(currentItem, nextItem)>0)
                swapItems(currentItem, nextItem);

              currentItem=nextItem;
              nextItem=nextItem->nextItem;
            }
        }
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: I suspect your j for loop will result into NPE because for 
suppose list is in ascending order so there is no swapping so after the compare condition value of currentItem and nextItem is as follows for j =0 currentItem = 1 / nextItem = 2, j = 1 currentItem = 2 / nextItem = 3, j = 2 currentItem = 3 / nextItem = 4 and now as nextItem already null so j = 3 it will give NPE for nextItem->nextItem.

Comment: Which call to compare has the problem?  What data have you tested it on?

Comment: i have no idea how to check which call did it, i just know it's one of them for sure, that's where the program breaks.

Comment: @jigar i'm not sure what you mean. the j loop is supposed to stop before it covers all the items, why wouldn't the break condition do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly the following is a problem.  Although the DL list is updated, the local values of `currentItem` and `nextItem` are not.  This needs to change when a swap occurs.

```
if(compare(currentItem, nextItem) > 0) 
  swapItems(currentItem, nextItem);

currentItem = nextItem;
nextItem = nextItem->nextItem;
```

Maybe

```
if(compare(currentItem, nextItem) > 0)  {
  swapItems(currentItem, nextItem);
  // No need to update currentItem, it is all ready the next item.
} else {
  currentItem = nextItem;
}

nextItem = nextItem->nextItem;
```

Comment: now when I think about it, it makes sense, so what should i basically do?

Comment: that's definately an error, but will it cause overruns?  i can only see that causing the process to advance too slowly

Comment: @Jasen, The `itemSize` count will be wrong for subsequent `for(i=0;i<itemSize;i++)` loop.

Comment: @Ryan Hopefully the update works for you.  Without knowing details of code's DL, there could other subtle issues with beginning/end cases.  There is more than 1 way to code a DL list.

Comment: @chux, yes, i see now, the inital count of itemsize will be too high.

Comment: on the other hand the the only way this function can be made to work is if swap() is changed to leave the pointers intact and swap the data parts of the list.  look at the interface.

Comment: @Jasen  Depends on the the unposted details of the DL list.

Answer (score 2):

the first problem is the function:

```
void SortItemList(Item* ptrFirstItem, 
                  int(*compare)(const Item*,const Item*))
```

that's not going to work. you need to be able to write to ptrFirstItem

```
void SortItemList(Item** ptrptrFirstItem, 
                  int(*compare)(const Item*,const Item*))
```

and swap needs that ability too.

Comment: you are right, that's another problem i bumped into, the first item disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification for the NPE problem
@Ryan Suppose if we have a sorted list and itemsize is 4 i.e index from 0 to 3. So 'i' will loop from 0 to 3. So for i = 0, 'j' will loop from 0 to 4 - 0 = 4. So when 'i' = 0 currItem is pointing to 0th element and nextItem points to 1st element. Now j will loop from 0 to 3. for j = 0 as list is sorted so there is no swapping. so now currentItem will point to 1st element and nextItem will point to 2nd element. For j = 1 at the end currentItem will point to 2nd element and nextItem will point to 3rd element. For j = 2 at the end currentItem will point to 3rd element and nextItem will point to 4th element. As 4th is null element so now nextItem has null value.for for j = 3 at the end currentItem will point to 4th element and nextItem will result into NPE as null.nextItem will result into NPE